# Sorting numbers with multiple decimal point in python

Tags: python, sorting

I have atext file and  which contains the following:

```
02.03.04@@
02.04.01@@
02.04.03.02@@
02.06.04.01@@
02.06.04.02@@
02.06.09@@
02.13.01@@
02.13.02@@
1.01@@
1.02@@
1.03@@
1.04@@
1.05@@
1.06@@
1.07@@
1.08@@
1.09@@
1.1@@
2.24@@
4.12@@
```

I need to sort it .As you see numbers starting with 1, 2 etc are already sorted using sorted().but numbers like '02.04.03.02@@'are sorted seperately But logically it should be after 1. How to do this in Python ? do i split at '.' and then compare individually?

Answer (score 6):

Split and map to integers in a key:

```
sorted(inputlist, key=lambda v: [int(i) for i in v.rstrip('@').split('.')])
```

This produces a list of integers for each line, and these are then sorted lexicographically; e.g. on the first element that differs.

Demo:

```
>>> sample = '''\
... 02.03.04@@
... 02.04.01@@
... 02.04.03.02@@
... 02.06.04.01@@
... 02.06.04.02@@
... 02.06.09@@
... 02.13.01@@
... 02.13.02@@
... 1.01@@
... 1.02@@
... 1.03@@
... 1.04@@
... 1.05@@
... 1.06@@
... 1.07@@
... 1.08@@
... 1.09@@
... 1.1@@
... 2.24@@
... 4.12@@
... '''.splitlines()
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> sorted(sample, key=lambda v: [int(i) for i in v.rstrip('@').split('.')])
['1.01@@', '1.1@@', '1.02@@', '1.03@@', '1.04@@', '1.05@@', '1.06@@', '1.07@@', '1.08@@', '1.09@@', '02.03.04@@', '02.04.01@@', '02.04.03.02@@', '02.06.04.01@@', '02.06.04.02@@', '02.06.09@@', '02.13.01@@', '02.13.02@@', '2.24@@', '4.12@@']
>>> pprint(_)
['1.01@@',
 '1.1@@',
 '1.02@@',
 '1.03@@',
 '1.04@@',
 '1.05@@',
 '1.06@@',
 '1.07@@',
 '1.08@@',
 '1.09@@',
 '02.03.04@@',
 '02.04.01@@',
 '02.04.03.02@@',
 '02.06.04.01@@',
 '02.06.04.02@@',
 '02.06.09@@',
 '02.13.01@@',
 '02.13.02@@',
 '2.24@@',
 '4.12@@']
```

Comment: Would `key=lambda x: float(x.rstrip("@"))` be an acceptable alternative to the list of ints?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: no, because there are numbers with 3 components here, which are not valid float numbers.

Comment: When am trying in the code its throwing  " ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x02'" @MartijinPieters

Comment: @nij_wiz: you have additional characters in your data you did not include in your question. What does `print repr(line)` produce for the line that throws that exception?

Comment: I did not get @martijinPieters .The  data is same.

Comment: I am using the same data but am not getting the sorted list.where am i going wrong  @MartijnPieters

Comment: @nij_wiz: no, the data is not the same. It may **print** the same because `\x02` bytes are not printable, but the contents are not the same as strings without those bytes. Please try and print each line with `repr(line)` and tell us what the actual contents are.

Comment: if I try  to reprint the sample: for s in sample:
 print repr(s)

 
'02.03.04@@'
'02.04.01@@'
'02.04.03.02@@'
'02.06.04.01@@'
'02.06.04.02@@'
'02.06.09@@'
'02.13.01@@'
'02.13.02@@'
'1.01@@'
'1.02@@'
'1.03@@'
'1.04@@'
'1.05@@'
'1.06@@'
'1.07@@'
'1.08@@'
'1.09@@'
'1.1@@'
'2.24@@'
'4.12@@'
' ' @MartijnPieters

Comment: @nij_wiz: yet you get a value error because at least one of those lines contains `\x02` and possibly other such non-printable bytes.

Comment: I  have figured out the problem and now  its printing but  sorting isn't happening  Just see the  succeeding comment

Comment: Is there any python inbuilt function to compare such numbers? (16.7.2 > 6.4.2)? Basically I am trying to compare versions of an application and so the decimal point can be arbitrary

Comment: @newbie: those are not numbers. Those are, at best, *software versions*. Numbers don't have more than one decimal point.

Comment: @newbie: see [How do I compare version numbers in Python?](//stackoverflow.com/q/11887762)

Answer (score 0):

A very close variant of Martijn's answer can be used for a slightly different (and probably more common) use case of sorting numbers-as-strings according to an outline numbering system, such as for decimal-based hierarchical headings. For example, heading numbers in a legal contract or for book chapters/sections/subsections.

```
>>> unordered_headings = ['3.1', '1.2.2', '1.2.1', '2.5', '3', '2.4', '1.1', '1', '2', '2.10', '2.2', '2.3', '2.6', '2.11', '2.8', '2.9', '2.7', '1.2', '2.1']
>>> ordered_headings = sorted(unordered_headings, key=lambda v: [int(i) for i in v.split('.')])
>>> ordered_headings
['1', '1.1', '1.2', '1.2.1', '1.2.2', '2', '2.1', '2.2', '2.3', '2.4', '2.5', '2.6', '2.7', '2.8', '2.9', '2.10', '2.11', '3', '3.1']
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
['1',    
 '1.1',  
 '1.2',  
 '1.2.1',
 '1.2.2',
 '2',    
 '2.1',  
 '2.2',  
 '2.3',  
 '2.4',
 '2.5',
 '2.6',
 '2.7',
 '2.8',
 '2.9',
 '2.10',
 '2.11',
 '3',
 '3.1']
>>>
```